# How to run DotNetNuke 6.2 under asp.net 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, installation, dotnetnuke

I just installed dnn 6.2 fresh as a .net 3.5 application on windows 7 under iis 7.5 using the default app pool. I then go and change the default app pool to .net 4.0, load up my site, and get an iis 7.5 error - IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.21:

...
...

Most likely causes:

Managed handler is used; however, ASP.NET is not installed or is not installed completely.

There is a typographical error in the configuration for the handler module list.

Things you can try:

Install ASP.NET if you are using managed handler.

Ensure that the handler module's name is specified correctly. Module names are case-sensitive and use the format modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule".

Everything I've read on this says to only perform two steps:

1. change the app pool to run under .net 4.0 (restart app pool)
2. pull up your site and dnn will make the necessary changes to the web.config file

Note: the default app pool has modify permissions on my website folder and all sub folders/files.

How can I fix this error and get dnn to run under asp.net 4.0?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to me quite a bit when setting up a new machine. You need to register ASP .NET 4.0 with IIS you do that by using

aspnet_regiis

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

So go to your .net 4 directory from your command line, path will be something like this.
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
then in that directory run

aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

That will re-register 4.0 with IIS and you should be all set.